# nunit3-console.exe gives Access Denied error on running on a win 10 64 bit machine

Tags: nunit, nunit-console, nunit-3.0

I installed Nunit3 on my new windows 10 64 bit machine.
When I try to run the nunit3-console.exe it gives me an error. Access is denied.
I have administration rights on this machine.
I even tried running the Nunit exe as administrator, but still no luck.

Any idea what needs to be done to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the Nunit3 software and it started working. Not sure what exactly was the problem.